# Disable global keyboard shortcuts for specific application

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcuts

Is it possible to disable the GNOME (version 2) global keyboard shortcuts for a specific application?

I'm using the IntelliJ IDEA Java IDE under Ubuntu however some of the IDEA default keyboard shortcuts conflict with the GNOME shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>). I really don't want to change the conflicting shortcuts within IDEA. I need to use the default keymap for "compatibility" reasons.

I'm thinking of some kind of proxy command that redirects every keyboard activity to the application **when it has the focus**. Something like `kbdproxy idea.sh`.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I'm going crazy for this problem with IDEA.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi Unfortunately no :(

Comment: If you were using KDE, you can disable specific global shortcut from Global Keyboard Shortcut settings

Answer (score 1):

The latter two for workspace switching is possible to be disabled , download and install gconf-editor , locate this entry:

> move_to_workspace

[image]

And leave them empty should work.

Comment: These two shortcuts were just examples. There are others that conflict, too. I don't think it's a good solution to disable the conflicting GNOME shortcuts :-/ I still want to be able to use them outside of the application.

Comment: @Sven , You probably want to fire a bug report to the developers , ask them to grab all key events in X11.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question in stackoverflow expecting loads of excellent answers but got none.

My personal solution is currently:

1. Install very light weight wm like 'twm': (sudo apt-get install twm)
2. Kick off a concurrent X session with no wm: xinit /usr/bin/xterm -- :2
3. Switch to new X session: control-alt-F8
4. Start twm in xterm within new session: twm &
5. Run program, enjoy programs shortcuts and be happy, switching back to other X session with control-alt-F7

Comment: I also had to change /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config to say "allowed_users=anybody" in order for step 2 to work.