# How do I disable global keyboard shortcuts for a specific application?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, window-manager, blender

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 (KDE), but it would also be helpful to know how to do this on other official Ubuntu flavors.

On KDE, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L Mouse</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R Mouse</kbd> are global keyboard shortcuts to move and resize windows.

I experience problems when I try to use conflicting shortcuts in applications like Blender.  For example, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R Mouse</kbd> in Blender should allow me to loop select with the selection tool, but due to the global shortcut, it actually results in me grabbing the entire window to move it.

In most cases, it's easier to rebind the shortcut on the application itself than mess with global shortcuts, but Blender has so many shortcuts that I don't want to deviate from the default shortcuts in order to learn from tutorials and documentation.

I want to be able to use shortcuts in Blender that use the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, but I don't want to disable the global shortcuts altogether. I find them to be a huge quality of life improvement for window management.

**I would like to know how to disable global shortcuts on a per-application basis.**

*There is similar question "[Disable global keyboard shortcuts for specific application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62654/disable-global-keyboard-shortcuts-for-specific-application)" but it specifically pertains to GNOME2*

Answer (score 3):

**In KDE you can do this using "Window Rules"**.

- Open **System Settings**.
- Navigate to **Window Management** > **Window Rules**.

  *(Alternatively, you can search for and launch "**Window Rules**" directly from the Application launcher.)*
- Click "**New...**" to create a new window rule.
- On the "**Window Matching**" tab, you will set the conditions for your window rule:

  - Give your rule an easy to remember name under "**Description**".
  - Next to "**Window class (application)**", change the drop down to "**Exact Match**" and set the value of the adjacent field to `blender`.
  - Under "**Window types**", make sure that "**Normal Window**" is selected.
- Switch to the "**Appearance and Fixes**" tab:

  - Select "**Ignore global shortcuts**".
  - In the adjacent fields, change the drop down to "**Force**" and set the radio button to "**Yes**".
- Click "**OK**" to save the new rule and click "**Apply**" to apply the new rule.

Blender should now ignore global shortcuts.

For other applications, replace `blender` with the name of the application process. (ex. as it appears under KSysGuard)

Comment: Strangely this disables many but not all shortcuts. I assigned Ctrl-Ins to Copy, and it's still working.